# Do we ever learn why the Locust Queen looks so human?

Tags: gears-of-war-series

I was playing Gears 2, and I was struck by the Locust Queen's appearance, compared to the rest of the Locust

> I was not prepared for the fact that she looks *incredibly* humanoid compared to the rest of the Locust. I was prepared to buy "humanoid aliens" for the rest of the Locust, and their English grunts being translated, but the Queen looks very human neck-up.

Do we ever learn why? Is that in Gears 3, or Judgement?

Comment: I don't have the time right now to research and write a full explanation, but the short answer is "because she's human".

Comment: Spoilers can be hidden with `>!` prior to the statement.

Comment: and they a body can be edited by clicking the "edit" link under the tags

Answer (score 3, accepted):

That's mainly because

> Myrrah *is* a Human. She is a descendant of the scientists that are "responsible" for the locusts coming to be.

You can read more about [Myrrah](http://gearsofwar.wikia.com/wiki/Myrrah) and the [Locust](http://gearsofwar.wikia.com/wiki/Locust) on the [Gears of War Wikia](http://gearsofwar.wikia.com) if you would like to learn more, but I will try and summarize what I can here:

> The Locust were born out of mutation from being exposed to imulsion for extended periods of time while mining Sera. The infected population was gathered by the COG, and sent to New Hope for research, and to hopefully find a cure. Instead, they mutated further, into the Sires. Fearful of the media/political response of this, the scientists relocated, and sealed the Sires in Mt. Kadar. The Children of these Sires were mutated from birth, thus becoming the Locust.

Myrrah's title of Queen is self-given, and does not have power related to royalty or genealogy. Nonetheless, the Locust Horde is ardently devoted to their Queen.

> Myrrah resents humanity for forcing the Locust underground after New Hope was shut down. Where the COG saw mutated, poisoned humans Myrrah saw an evolved, stronger race.